# error trying to add a view to a UIViewController's view

Tags: ios

I need to make some updates to another persons code. I am trying to add a custom view to an existing `UIViewController`. The code I have is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect viewFrame=CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);
    MyImageView *bView=[[MyImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];

    [bView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubView:bView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

and I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I thought this should work. Is it possible to add a custom view in this way? Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
[self.view addSubview:bView];
```

not

```
[self.view addSubView:bView];
```

(no capitalized V in addSubview).